# Change array to an array of object php

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have this array:

```
array(3) {
  ["MANTRI KUPEDES"]=>
  int(11)
  ["JUNIOR STAFF 1"]=>
  int(10)
  ["PETUGAS ADM.KREDIT JUNIOR"]=>
  int(10)
}
```

I want to change it into this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#26 (2) {
    ["jabatan"]=>
    string(33) "MANTRI KUPEDES"
    ["total"]=>
    int(11)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#27 (2) {
    ["jabatan"]=>
    string(33) "JUNIOR STAFF 1"
    ["total"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#28 (2) {
    ["jabatan"]=>
    string(30) "PETUGAS ADM.KREDIT JUNIOR"
    ["total"]=>
    int(10)
  }
}
```

I tried:

```
$jabatans['jabatan'] = array_keys($counts);
$jabatans['jumlah'] = array_values($counts);
```

But still didn't get what I wanted. Any ideas? I wanted to render this to CanvasJs using CodeIgniter 3.0.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Yap I have tried this

Comment: $jabatans['jabatan'] = array_keys($counts);
$jabatans['jumlah'] = array_values($counts); but still didn't get what I wanted

Comment: Of course you did not, because all that does is get the keys in one array, and the values in another. Calling this an "attempt" is really rather a joke to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Build an array with the keys and values and cast it to an object:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $result[] = (object)['jabatan' => $key, 'total' => $val];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do foreach loop to assign the old array to the new array of object

```
$array = array(
  "MANTRI KUPEDES"=>11,
  "JUNIOR STAFF 1"=> 10,
  "PETUGAS ADM.KREDIT JUNIOR"=>10,
);
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
  $obj = new stdClass();
  $obj->jabatan = $key;
  $obj->total = $val;
  array_push($newArray, $obj);
}
```

Source : https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php